# Why is my call of the CUDA math library sqrt() function failing?

Tags: c++, c, math, cuda, square-root

I am new to Cuda, I have the following function:

```
__global__ void square(float *myArrayGPU)
{
   myArrayGPU[threadIdx.x] = sqrt(threadIdx.x);
}
```

I want to use the cuda math library, I tried to `#include "math.h"` but I still get the error

`error: calling a __host__ function("__sqrt") from a __global__ function("square") is not allowed`

Any idea what library should I include to use the `sqrt`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`threadIdx.x` is of type int. CUDA math library is overloaded only for single precision (`float`) and double precision (`double`). You need to supply either a 'float' or 'double' type parameter to `sqrt()` for the CUDA version of `sqrt()` to be called.

Change

```
myArrayGPU[threadIdx.x] = sqrt(threadIdx.x);
```

into

```
myArrayGPU[threadIdx.x] = sqrt( (float) threadIdx.x);
```

For more detailed information, take a look at the [CUDA sqrt() prototype documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE_g1c6fe34b4ac091e40eceeb0bae58459f.html).

Answer (score 9):

`sqrt` expects a floating type variable. Try `sqrt((float)(threadIdx.x))`

Comment: Good answer, but unfortunately Harshil Sharma beat you to the 'textbook version'... :-)